# Typescript function which returns one item from an array with proper type

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I have a function that returns one item from an array:

```
function oneItem(arr: any[]) {
  return arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

I'd like to have approriate types for this.

---

*What I've Tried:*

```
type ValuesOf<T extends any[]>= T[number];
function oneItem<ARRAY extends any[]>(arr: ARRAY): ValuesOf<ARRAY> { ... }

const a = oneItem(["foo", "bar"]);
// typeof a is (string) instead of ("foo" | "bar")
```

Found here (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965)

---

**How do I return a single item from an array with proper type?**

---

EDIT: I figured it out for readonly arrays:

```
type ValuesOf<T extends readonly any[]>= T[number];
function oneItem<ARRAY extends readonly any[]>(arr: ARRAY): ValuesOf<ARRAY> { ... }

const a = oneItem(["foo", "bar"] as const);
```

Comment: I miss something -- why `function oneItem<T>(arr: T[]): T` is not good enough?

Comment: `const b = oneItem(["foo", "bar"]);` ---> `typeof b (string)`

Comment: and what it should be?

Comment: Ah, I think I understood! Need to learn how to read :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "proper" type, I guess you mean you want the narrowest possible type the compiler can infer.

Whether or not this is "proper" is in the eye of the beholder; the runtime code `let x = 0` could have many possible typings in TypeScript, and the compiler has to pick just one of them unless you annotate the type yourself.

For example, I might want it to be interpreted as `let x: number = 0` which is the default compiler behavior and which makes sense if I plan to assign different numbers to `x` later.  Or I might want `let x: 0 | 1 = 0` because I'm only going to write code like `x = y & 1` and I know that only those values will come out.  Or I might want `let x: 0 = 0` because `x` will always be `0` (although presumably I would use `const` in that case).  Or maybe I want `let x: number | string = 0` because sometimes I will assign `string` values to it.  Or maybe I want any other crazy type that includes `0` as a value.

If you don't annotate it yourself, then the compiler has to infer the type, so it makes an assumption: non-`readonly` and non-`const` values will tend to be inferred as a "widened" type like `string`, `number`, or `boolean`, while `readonly` and `const` values will tend to be inferred as a "narrow" [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) like `"foo`", `0`, or `true`.

Sometimes the compiler's default assumption won't match the intent of the developer.  That doesn't mean the compiler did anything wrong; it's not as if it takes `let x = 0` and infers `string` for `x`.  It just means the developer might be required to put in some more effort to communicate his or her intent.

---

So, when I write `["foo", "bar"]`, the compiler tends to infer that as `string[]`. If I want something else, I can annotate it myself. Let's start with this version of your function:

```
function oneItem<T>(arr: readonly T[]): T {
  return arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Here are some outputs:

```
let arr1 = ["foo", "bar"]; // inferred as string[]
const res1 = oneItem(arr1); // string

let arr2: Array<"foo" | "bar"> = ["foo", "bar"];
const res2 = oneItem(arr2); // "foo" | "bar"

let arr3: ["foo", "bar"] = ["foo", "bar"];
const res3 = oneItem(arr3); // "foo" | "bar"

let arr4: readonly ["foo", "bar"] = ["foo", "bar"];
const res4 = oneItem(arr4); // "foo" | "bar"

let arr5 = ["foo", "bar"] as const; // inferred as readonly ["foo", "bar"];
const res5 = oneItem(arr5);
```

You can see that `arr1` uses the default `string[]` inferred type, and thus `string` comes out of the function.  For `arr2`, `arr3`, and `arr4`, I've annotated the arrays as progressively narrower types, and all of them allow `"foo" | "bar"` to come out of the function.  The last one, `arr5`, uses a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to infer the type as the narrowest value it can, corresponding to that of `arr4`.

So one way for you to proceed is just to specify the value's type more narrowly.

---

Of course, in your use case, you have something like

```
const resArrayLiteral = oneItem(["foo", "bar"]); // string
```

And you would like `"foo" | "bar"` to come out instead of `string`.  Why should the *caller* of `oneItem()` have to ask the compiler to narrow the type of the array literal `["foo", "bar"]`?  Can't the *implementer* of `oneItem()` use some sort of contextual typing hint to tell the compiler to interpret things more narrowly?

Well, kind of, yes.  It's just not pretty.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

function oneItem<T extends Narrowable>(arr: readonly T[]): T {
  return arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Here we are giving `T` a [constraint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Narrowable`, a union type of a bunch of things including `string`, `number`, and `boolean`.  In fact, the `Narrowable` type is a kind of tedious version of `unknown`, since most anything should be assignable to it.  But `Narrowable` gives the compiler a hint (see [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)) that you'd like to see `T` inferred as a literal type, if possible.

Let's see if it works:

```
const resArrayLiteral = oneItem(["foo", "bar"]); // "foo" | "bar"
```

Looks good now! `T` is inferred as `"foo" | "bar"` and not `string`.

---

As I said, though: it's not pretty.  There's an [open issue, (microsoft/TypeScript#30680)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), suggesting that we be able to write the `oneItem()` signature as something like

```
function oneI<const T>(arr: readonly T[]): T; // currently invalid syntax
```

where the `const` is in the signature, and it behaves similarly to having the caller use `as const`.  Not sure if that issue will ever go anywhere, though.  For now, we have to jump through hoops like `Narrowable`.

---

Also, please note that the above `T extends Narrowable` does nothing to change the behavior of `arr1`.  If you write `let arr1 = ["foo", "bar"]`, then `arr` will be inferred as `string[]`.  Once it's a `string[]`, the compiler has forgotten all about `"foo"` and `"bar"` as literal types.  And thus `oneItem(arr1)` will return `string`; `T` will be inferred as `string`.  So at some point you might find yourself needing to write narrow types yourself, if you want them.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgJwQewO5wEYBtoF4oDOwCAlgHYDmUAPlGQK4C2GECNUGyyOcZ7BIZt3bIMAKwgBjYO3pkAJhABm5CPPYA3ZCXW0GWLOwDeAXwDcAKAtK50ksj4OIASWARGAHgAqUCAA83BQJYRBR0bAgAPgAKUIAuKAQIOHkHLBAoLwBtAF0ASgSfIwsoRIhgegQ+UKyAP1rogFk4YAALADoEXlTGaLyoACooUPacSja8nMsTKygLAHoB61tge0cyFw9JByJMyKhYpASklLSM7PzCsyh5+ahJSqSyYHSocg04LB1CEGe4PwsA3mVhwMlCAEYoPgsgAiJRcGEAGigMIwiBhUxud3ISlYSXUcGCRFIlFyFm2ZF2SQIkPwTlc7kOCHBeWut0IxHIFBB5WGSAATAkAIJIOAgDxwhHsVHo-bQyXIJEotEIDGWClUiAEflQqD0ty9UL81lYlHwxXSlUwnlgpAAZgSsPNSplqpyuqdCORrrV5J2Mmpdt1+sZoTtJvZCphlvRNr5CAALMdkqkyK9PYrvVb3fLnVn0VM-ZSA1qE8GNgzDUgExG7lGY6q46EAKweqP5t3DYIa4Bs7FkXFINRdsqnNMZDMu7Pq-1lAitukVg1M5usqxFzUEEVdEAAGRIbi6hkXLmXk47GNrZqltB964sQA)